# Changing Zipcode from a child component (react native node js)

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-hooks, formik

I have a home screen that is capturing the location of the user using expo-location.

HomeScreen is getting the zipcode like this:

`

```
const [zipcode, setZipcode] = useState("");                 
const GetCurrentLocation = async () => {
                    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

                    if (status !== 'granted') {
                        toastRef.current.show(
                            "Permission to access location was denied",
                            3000
                        );
                    }

                    let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();


                    if (coords) {
                        const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
                        let response = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
                            latitude,
                            longitude
                        });

                        for (let item of response) {
                            let zip = `${item.postalCode}`;

                            setZipcode(zip);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

`

I'm sending using props the zipcode={zipcode} to the child (I have added an icon in Home Screen, that when you click brings a modal with a component called "Change Zipcode" wish literally is the form that I want to use to the users change their zipcode manually)

ChangeZipcode.js :

What I'm trying to do, is to update the zipcode in HomeScreen with the new zipcode that the users are changing manually but I don't know how.

I was trying to create an usestate called zipcode and then do a useEffect with the zipcodeNew from the form, but not success.

```
export function ChangeZipcode(props) {


    const {zipcodeOld} = props;
    const [zipcode, setZipcode] = useState("");

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: initialValues(),
        validationSchema: validationSchema(),
        validateOnChange: false,
        onSubmit: async (formValue) => {
    
            try {
                const zipcodeNew = formValue.zipcode;
                useEffect(() => {
                    if(zipcodeNew) {
                        setZipcode(zipcodeNew);
                    }
                  }, [zipcode]);

    
            } catch (error) {
                Toast.show({
                    type: "error",
                    position: "bottom",
                    text1: "Error updating the zipcode",
                })
            
            }
            console.log(zipcode);
        }

    
    });
```

If someone can help me would be amazing!!!

Comment: I think it should work if you also pass `setZipCode` as prop. Then you dont need to create any state for the zip code in the child component

Comment: Totally right man! Worked perfect passing the setZipCode